# RabbitMQ Mutual authentication using self signed certificates

Tags: .net, ssl, rabbitmq, digital-certificate, mutual-authentication

I have religiously followed the instructions given at the RabbitMQ site to set up mutual authentication between a RabbitMQ server and a .Net client (using the official RabbitMQ client available at RabbitMQ.com)

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html

---

However, The instructions are missing a key point. For the peer certificate to be validated in the RabbitMQ server, A user needs to be mapped (for impersonation) to the peer certificate as described below

https://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyabecker/Using-SSL-client-certificates-for-authentication-with-RabbitMQ

---

But, When the certificates are exchanged during a handshake, RabbitMQ server is looking for a username called **'O=client,CN=MyServer.com'**  instead of 'CN=MyServer.com'

If I create this user with the required privileges, everything succeeds as expected.

I would like to know what is the reason for the unexpected 'O=client' part in the username. It is not documented anywhere in the RabbitMQ site.

Has anyone come across this?
**What is the name of the user you have created for impersonating the peer/client?**

---

Both RabbitMQ server and client versions are 3.6.5

Erlang version: 18

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at this recently and it is configurable on start up in docker by providing additional config as below

```
[
{rabbit, [
    {auth_mechanisms, ['EXTERNAL']},
    {loopback_users, []},
    {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
    {ssl_options, [{cacertfile, "etc/docker/certs.d/ca_certificate.pem"},
                {certfile,   "etc/docker/certs.d/server_certificate.pem"},
                {keyfile,    "etc/docker/certs.d/private_key.pem"},
                {verify,     verify_peer},
                {password,  ""},
                {fail_if_no_peer_cert, false}],
                {ssl_cert_login_from, common_name}}         
]}
].
```

The key here being the `ssl_cert_login_from` option allows you to use only the CN of the certificate

Removing this option enables the use of the DN